# How to change the name of result set in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, biztalk

I have a Generated schema in BizTalk. Its response contains multiple result sets starting with StoredProcedureResultSet0 to 6.
Is it possible to give a meaning name to these results set ?
If yes then how can I achieve it ?

Thanks in Advance.[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are two answers to this question.

**NO.**  The results sets are names simple in the order in which they would appear in the output.  This is the programmed behavior of the sqlBinding and cannot be changed.

**YES.**  You can use a Map to change the names and structure to any format you need.